# How do I change the size of the navigation drawer menu item icons?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-menu

How do I change the size of the `<item>` elements inside a Navigation Drawer element?

No matter what the icons always seem to resize automatically to 24dp like this:

[image]

I need to increase the size of the icons to 34 dps but the `<item>` elements don't seem to have any attribute to change this setting in the XML:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: css?  what are you using?

Comment: @BrianThomas its an Android app, the XML you see on the bottom image is the main_drawer.xml file.

Comment: ok so your looking for an unknown attribute?  you dont have any xsl styling those?

Comment: For achieving this you have to design custom drawer with `RecyclerView` or `ListVIew`

Comment: @Nilesh can you elaborate please?

@ BrianTomas yes, there is no attribute for that, it is not like a <ImageView> element

Answer (score 5):

You can change the size of navigationView icon by overriding design_navigation_icon_size attribute. You can put it in dimens and because you're overriding a private attribute, you need to include tools:override="true"

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_icon_size" tools:override="true">40dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 1):

copy this in your Navigation drawer xml.

```
app:itemTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
```

there are many text appearence to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

[NavigationView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) implements the [material design specs for a navigation drawer](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html). Therefore the size of the icons are fixed at 24dp. You'd have to build your own navigation drawer to break the material design specs if you want 34dp icons.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of the Design Specs, any idea on how to override this setting without rebuilding the drawer? Maybe at run-time? Otherwise, could you please elaborate or link any resource related to "building your own navigation drawer?"

Comment: If you want to use `NavigationView`, you are stuck with the design specs on purpose. The `NavigationView` is just one of the views in your `DrawerLayout` - you can replace it with your own `ListView` or `RecyclerView` with whatever item layouts you want.